# Two select statements

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` ) 
FROM a
WHERE `marks` >=90
```

The above gives me count of student with marks greater than 90,

```
COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` )
4
```

Now I want two answers, one with marks > 90 and another >80

Something like this

```
COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` )  |COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` )
    4                                            5
```

This is what I have tried after google search

```
  select

count_1 =( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` ) 
FROM a
WHERE `marks` >=90),


count_2 =( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `student_id` ) 
FROM a
WHERE `marks` >=80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression with an aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when `marks` >= 90 then 1 else 0 end) count_1,
  sum(case when `marks` >= 80 then 1 else 0 end) count_2
FROM a
```

Then if you have more counts to get you will add more case expressions.

Or you can use:

```
SELECT 
  count(distinct case when `marks` >= 90 then `student_id` end) count_1,
  count(distinct case when `marks` >= 80 then `student_id` end) count_2
FROM a
```

Comment: @user2300435 You are welcome, your query was on the right path. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpliest answer would be by using implicit boolean condition since MySQL supports it,

```
SELECT  SUM(marks >= 90) Count_1,
        SUM(marks >= 80) Count_1
FROM    a
WHERE   marks >= 80
```

The `WHERE` clause makes the searching more faster since it will filter the records first than running through all records.